# How to send list from a fragment to a custom view class in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view

I have created a fragment from which I want to send a list to a custom view class how can I send it. I have tried to use custom class constructor but it gives error. Any suggestion for this problem?

```
public class BannerSliderView extends FrameLayout {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private PageIndicatorView pageIndicatorView;
private List<Banner> bannersList;
private BannerViewPagerAdapter bannerViewPagerAdapter;
public BannerSliderView(@NonNull Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public BannerSliderView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, -1);
}

public BannerSliderView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.banner_slider_layout, null);
    addView(view);
    bannersList=new ArrayList<>();
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(valueInPixels);
    pageIndicatorView = view.findViewById(R.id.pager_indicator);
    bannerViewPagerAdapter=new 
    BannerViewPagerAdapter(getContext(),bannersList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(bannerViewPagerAdapter);
    pageIndicatorView.setViewPager(viewPager);
    
}
public void setBannersList(List<Banner> bannersList) {
    this.bannersList = bannersList;
}
```

Home Fragment

```
public class HomeFragment {
    bannerSliderView=view.findViewById(R.id.BannerSliderView);
    Banner banner = new Banner("Promotion", "Noor Designer", String.valueOf(R.drawable.loginbackground));
    bannerList.add(banner);
    bannerList.add(banner);
    bannerList.add(banner);
    bannerSliderView.setBannersList(bannerList);
}
```

Comment: Post whole code what you tried then only you will get answers.

Comment: Just create a Setter in custom view class .

Comment: @ADM list is received in class but not showing on UI what is the problem?

Comment: problem is that you didn't posted a single line of code

Comment: You create setter in custom view and then Invalidate the view That's how its works . Without any code nobody can help you so add the code with your question.

Comment: @ADM check the code I have pasted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Invalidate the `View` Since your data is dynamic you can do all the in it stuff after setting the data. Below is an example which should work.

```
public class BannerSliderView extends FrameLayout {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private PageIndicatorView pageIndicatorView;
private List<Banner> bannersList;
private BannerViewPagerAdapter bannerViewPagerAdapter;
public BannerSliderView(@NonNull Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public BannerSliderView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, -1);
}

public BannerSliderView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.banner_slider_layout, null);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(valueInPixels);
    pageIndicatorView = view.findViewById(R.id.pager_indicator);
    addView(view);
}

public void setBannersList(List<Banner> bannersList) {
    this.bannersList = bannersList;
    bannerViewPagerAdapter = new
            BannerViewPagerAdapter(getContext(), bannersList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(bannerViewPagerAdapter);
    pageIndicatorView.setViewPager(viewPager);
}
}
```

With this approach `bannerViewPagerAdapter` will be `null` before any call to  `setBannersList` . Or you can just set the adapter inside `#init` and just update data in `setBannersList`.